# Вывод пар уникальных значений из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Схема БД состоит из таблицы:

```
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
```

В таблице `PC` для каждого ПК, однозначно определяемого уникальным кодом – code, указаны модель – model (внешний ключ), скорость - speed (процессора в мегагерцах), объем памяти - ram (в мегабайтах), размер диска - hd (в гигабайтах), скорость считывающего устройства - cd (например, '4x') и цена - price.

---

> Найдите пары моделей PC, имеющих одинаковые скорость и RAM. В результате каждая пара указывается только один раз, т.е. (i,j), но не (j,i), Порядок вывода: модель с большим номером, модель с меньшим номером, скорость и RAM.

Делаю вот так, некоторые тесты проходит, но потом выдает неверный ответ (система пишет, что неверное количество строк):

```
Select PC.model, PC1.model, PC.speed, PC.RAM from PC 
inner join PC as PC1 on PC.model != PC1.model 
where PC.ram = PC1.ram and PC.speed = PC1.speed 
and PC.model > PC1.model;
```

Comment: Ой, прошу прощения, описался, количество строк, конечно

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это прямое нарушение правил сайта sql-ex. На сайте есть своя линия поддержки для вопросов по сложностям в решении задач.

Comment: @pegoopik при чем тут правила какого-то sql-ex вообще? что-что а это точно не может являться причиной закрытия вопроса.  у нас тут свои правила, и в них есть только одно требование про учебные задачи - представить вариант своего решения. и оно тут вроде выполнено.

Comment: вообще реально, что это за говносхема данных? там на таких примерах чему учат то? тому как неправильно формировать структуру БД ?

Comment: @pegoopik это не повод удалять кусок вопроса и заменять его на какое-то странное предупреждение! Если вас возмущает нарушение правил решения задач какого-то стороннего сайта - обратитесь к администрации sql-ex. Хотите, чтобы другие знали о таком нарушении - ограничтесь комментарием.

Comment: @pegoopik и да, нарушение правил sql-ex не может служить причиной закрытия вопроса на Stack Overflow. Пожалуйста, используйте механизим закрытия по назначению - для улучшения вопросов. А не для применения правил сторонних сайтов.

Comment: @teran какое еще "выполните js код"??

Comment: @PashaPash :D да я тоже думал сначала откатить правку просто :) потом сделал urlencode вопроса, поскольку, возможно фактически публикация контента в открытом виде нарушает авторские права третьих лиц.

Comment: а по сабжу, вопрос относится только к таблице PC, на кой нам описание всего остального?

Comment: @teran грохнул лишнее. И вот думаю, условие тоже в цитирование обернуть или так оставить ..

Comment: @teran я не нашел ссылки на хоть какую-то лицензию на sql-ex. Единственный запрет - это упоминание, что учетку участника могут удалить за публикацию задачи на стороннем сайте. Я не против, пусть удаляют.

Comment: @PashaPash, всё верно. С удалением части вопроса перегнул. А вот то, что упоминание о сайте убрали из вопроса, спасибо. Я бы ещё сам вопрос перефразировал без потери смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ваше решение с виду верное. Однако, поскольку мы оперируем  не первичными ключами `code`, а внешним `model` то следует исключить возможные повторы, добавив оператор `distinct`. Ведь у вас в заголовке вопроса так и написано "*уникальных* пар"

Также следует заметить, что ваше условие `pc.model != pc1.model` полностью исключается условием `pc.model > pc1.model`, поэтому избыточно. В дополнение, все эти условия имеет смысл перенести в условия соединения, где им и место. Ибо зачем делать произведение таблиц, а потом фильтровать результат, если можно сразу склеить только нужные строки.

```
SELECT distinct PC.model, PC1.model, PC.speed, PC.RAM 
FROM PC 
INNER JOIN  PC as PC1 ON (
       PC.model > PC1.model 
       AND PC.ram = PC1.ram 
       AND PC.speed = PC1.speed 
)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение, а также за замечания, все получилось, ответ правильный.

Comment: ого, аж два минуса :) пишите хоть за что :)